# Determining Oxidation Number

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, oxidation-state

In NH3, what's the oxidation number of H? Should it be +3 or +1? I'm a little confused what to use.

Comment: What was your reason for ruling out all numbers except +1 and +3?

Answer (score 2):

The oxidation number of hydrogen is mostly $1$. Unless it is in elemental state, i.e. as $\ce{H2}$, here the oxidation number of $\ce{N}$ is $-3$ and hydrogen is $+1$.
Hydrogen can also take up $-1$ depending on the atom it is attached to. What you really need to lookout for is the electronegativity of the atom attached to it.

[image]

Comment: OS of H isn't always +1, it is only in case when H is linked with a non-metal. NaH, MgH2 are some examples of -1 OS of H.